# MySQL error, I can't see what's wrong

Tags: php, mysql

I am using this code to enter update user permissions on a web app:

```
$updaters = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++){    
  if (isset($_POST['permsA['.$i.']']))        
   $updaters[] = '`'.$i.'` = \''.mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['permsA['.$i.']']).'\'';
  }
$insert = mysqli_query($db,'UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET '.implode(',', $updaters).    'WHERE `userid` = '.$id)or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

The error I get is from the SQL:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `userid` = 1' at line 1
```

I can't seem to be able to rewrite the code to remove the error :(

this is the code to generate permsA

```
<?
while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($get_perms)){
$pname = $i[pname];
$id = $i[id];
?>
<div><input type="checkbox" tabindex="1" name="permsA[<? echo $id;?>]" value="1" <? if($permissionid[$id] == '1') {echo ' checked="checked" ';}?> /><?echo htmlspecialchars($pname);?></div>
<? } ?>
```

Here is the exact query that produces the error:

```
$insert = mysqli_query($db,'UPDATE `tbl_perms` '.$updaters.' WHERE `userid` = '.$id) or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Here is what this sql generates:

```
UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET WHERE `userid` = 1
```

And here's a variable dump from the variables after POST `var_dump($_POST['permsA'])`:

`array(22) { [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "1" [3]=> string(1) "1" [4]=> string(1) "1" [5]=> string(1) "1" [6]=> string(1) "1" [8]=> string(1) "1" [9]=> string(1) "1" [10]=> string(1) "1" [11]=> string(1) "1" [12]=> string(1) "1" [13]=> string(1) "1" [14]=> string(1) "1" [15]=> string(1) "1" [16]=> string(1) "1" [17]=> string(1) "1" [18]=> string(1) "1" [19]=> string(1) "1" [20]=> string(1) "1" [21]=> string(1) "1" [22]=> string(1) "1" [23]=> string(1) "1" }`

Comment: echo out the query before it runs, and post that here.

Comment: What does this return?  echo 'UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET '.implode(',', $updaters).    ' WHERE `userid` = '.$id;

Comment: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/bsraf/public_html/control/useredit.php on line 21
UPDATE tbl_perms SET WHERE userid = 4

Comment: Why don't you try to format your code a bit first?

Comment: Actually, the most recent edit still isn't what we need. Robert H's comment points out what we're looking for. What we need to see is the *generated* query, not the code that generates the query. It should look something like "`UDPATE \`tbl_perms\` SET \`1\`=1, \`2\`=0, \`5\`=1 WHERE userid = 1`" You know, what's actually producing the error. Also, we don't need to see the code that generates the form fields, we need to see the contents of $_POST['permsA']. Try `var_dump($_POST['permsA'])`.

Comment: Ok, edited OP to show - now it looks like there's something wrong.

Comment: And what's the query? You best not be trollin'.

Comment: '$insert = mysqli_query($db,'UPDATE `tbl_perms` '.$updaters.' WHERE `userid` = '.$id.') or die(mysqli_error($db));

Comment: Again, that's the code that generates and runs the query. For the umpteenth time, we need to see the ***GENERATED*** query. As I've said before, the query should look something like: `UDPATE \`tbl_perms\` SET \`1\`=1, \`2\`=0, \`5\`=1 WHERE userid = 1`. When you answer a question, someone says "That's not what I'm asking for", gives an example of what they are asking for and asks again, giving the SAME ANSWER is not only wrong but incredibly annoying.

Comment: Ah right, I am really sorry for this.

Here is what it gives, UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET WHERE `userid` = 1

Edited OP to reflect changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 potential issues:

- Put a space before WHERE
- your implode function may be leaving a trailing comma which will throw off the query. rtrim(implode(...), ',') to correct

Comment: `implode()` does not leave a trailing join character. http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

Comment: It does if you have an empty item at the end and why I used qualifiers like potential and may :)

Answer (score 2):

Add a space before your WHERE clause but after the apostrophe `' WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

Add a space before WHERE

And be sure that $updaters is filled.

---

Try this:

```
$updaters = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++){    
  if (isset($_POST['permsA['.$i.']']))        
   $updaters[] = '`'.$i.'` = \''.mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['permsA['.$i.']']).'\'';
}
$updaters = (count($updaters) > 0) ? ' Set '.implode (',', $updaters).' ' : '';
$insert = mysqli_query($db,'UPDATE `tbl_perms` '.$updaters.' WHERE `userid` = '.$id)or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if it's the problem, but you have no space before the `WHERE` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

THe answer is already said i guess, but i would advise you to you parameterised queries since they're safer and spare you the trouble of string debugging.

Apperently it is not fixed. Can you post the whole query that is executed?

Answer (score 0):

If you declared your post field name like so: name="permsA[$i]" then you have to access it this way: $_POST['permsA'][$i].

Answer (score 0):

There looks to be a logic error with how you reference $_POST values. When you [name input variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays) with a square brace suffix (e.g. "permsA[]", "permsA[3]"), PHP parses them as arrays. Try:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 24; $i++){    
    if (isset($_POST['permsA'][$i])) {
       $updaters[] = "`$i`='".mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['permsA'][$i])."'";
    }
}
```

Or, better yet, use [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) and prepared queries:

```
// keys of $permsAFields are keys we want to allow for input array 'permsA' 
static $permsAFields = array_fill(1, 24, 1);
...
// filter permsA
$permsA = array_intersect_key($_POST['permsA'], $permsAFields);
if (count($permsA)) {
    $query = $db->prepare("UPDATE `tbl_perms` SET `" . implode('`=?, `', array_keys($permsA)) . "`=? WHERE `userid`=?");
    $permsA[]=$id;
    $query->execute($permsA);
} else { // invalid input
    ...
}
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `userid` = 4' at line 1

Comment: I'm not certain what the point of your comment is. Why don't you try what others have suggested and post the query and contents of `$_POST['permsA']` in your question?

Comment: that is the query of $_POST['permsA'][$i] in the question, or do you want the query that generates the permsA ?

Comment: We want to see the query that produces the error you're asking about.

Comment: I don't know how you managed to edit yourself, but it's a rather unpleasant visual.